# FIREBASE - Encadear promises para redirecionar página somente após salvar dados no Firestore Firebase e atualizar Display name

Tags: javascript, firebase

Fala, pessoal. Tudo bem?

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web com o Firebase e como o método auth() só aceita e-mail e senha, estou atualizando o displayName e salvando o restando dos dados (cpf, por exemplo) no Firestore, no momento de criação do usuário.

Até aí, tudo certo. Porém, empaquei ao tentar redirecioná-lo para à nova página, APÓS esses processos (displayName e Firestore).

Primeiro, chamei as funções de displayName, Firestore e redirecionamento (usei o window.location.href) no .then do auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password), mas redirecionava antes de realizar os processos.

Depois tentei encadeá-los em promises, mas não deu muito certo.

```
document.getElementById('buttonSignupUser').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var email = document.getElementById('inputEmail').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var password2 = document.getElementById('password2').value;

    if (password == password2){
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(function() {
                console.log('user created');
                saveFirestore();
            }).then(function(){
                addDisplayName();
            }).then(function(){
                redirectSignup();
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                if (error.code == 'auth/invalid-email') {
                    console.log('Por favor, digite um e-mail válido');
                } else if (error.code == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                    console.log('Esse e-mail já está sendo utilizado');
                } 
            });
    } else {
        console.log('As senhas devem ser iguais');
    }

})
```

Essa é a função para salvar os dados complementares no Firestore:

```
function saveFirestore(){
    var email = document.getElementById('inputEmail').value;
    var name = document.getElementById('inputName').value;
    var cpf = document.getElementById('inputCPF').value;

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var uid;

        if (user != null) {
        uid = user.uid;  
        }

    firebase.firestore().collection('usuario').doc(uid).set({
        CPF: cpf,
        Email: email,
        Nome: name,
        Id: uid
    })
    console.log('saved firestore');
}
```

Essa é a função para atualizar o valor displayName

```
function addDisplayName(){
    var name = document.getElementById('inputName').value;
        firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({
        displayName: name
        }).then(function() {
            console.log('Display name added');
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

E por último, essa é a para redirecionar o usuário

```
function redirectSignup(){
    window.lotacion.href='logado.html'
}
```

Passei o dia tentando resolver isso, li sobre encadeamento de promises, promises.all, async/await, tentei usar um if/else...mas como estudo Javascript há pouco tempo, muitos assuntos ainda são complexos e, por isso, não consegui resolver.

Já agradeço a atenção, pessoal.
Abraços

Answer (score 1):

Tente colocar uma função dentro da outra. Deixando a função que deve ser realizada por último mais internamente.

```
    this.one().then(() => {
          this.two().then(() => { 
        });
    });
```

Comment: Fala, Edson. Beleza?

Um colega me ajudou hoje e chegou a essa conclusão
``
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => saveFirestore())
            .then(() => addDisplayName())
                .then(() => redirectSignUp())
                    .catch(err => {
                         console.log(err);
      });
``

Funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Muito legal que conseguiu resolver, parece uma boa solução. Infelizmente não consegui ajudá-lo.

Comment: Imagina, me ajudou sim...as dicas que você deu aqui serviram de base pra gente chegar nessa. Brigadão pela ajuda. Abração

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Edson. Obrigado pela resposta.

Segui sua dica e o código ficou dessa forma

`firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => {
            saveFirestore().then(() => {
                addDisplayName().then(() => {
                    redirectSignup();
                    });
                });
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })`

Quando fui executá-lo, obtive essa resposta: 
"saved firestore
main.js:14 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at main.js:8
    at r.g (auth.esm.js:17)
    at Dt (auth.esm.js:20)
    at Ct (auth.esm.js:20)
    at vt.t.Xb (auth.esm.js:19)
    at pt (auth.esm.js:13)"

Tentei adicionar as duas funções que precisam ser executadas primeiro, em uma promise.all, ficando com o código assim:

`firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => {
            Promise.all([addDisplayName(), saveFirestore()]).then(() => {
            redirectSignup();
                });
            });`

Dessa forma, as 3 funções foram executadas, mas a redirectSignup ainda foi realizada antes das 3 finalizarem (troquei o window.location.href por um console.log(), para ver quando ela seria chamada).

Tem alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo ou uma nova abordagem que possa usar para resolver esse problema?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia tentar fazer da seguinte maneira cada uma das funções:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(result);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO

Um colega me ajudou à chegar em uma conclusão. Espero que ajude mais pessoas.

`firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) .then(() => saveFirestore()) .then(() => addDisplayName()) .then(() => redirectSignUp()) .catch(err => { console.log(err); });`